# Fresh build a Application using multiple Databases

Tags: database

I'm a student and I have a question about architecture.

Is it common to use *multiple database* connections in a Java application when being in the first stage of the developing process?

Best regards ,

Erik Student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Erik and welcome to StackOverflow.

To answer your question:

That very much depends on the architecture/usecases of the application. A couple of examples that could motivate the use of multiple database connections are;

- Needed data is stored/owned on different locations
- Microservice architecture (https://smartbear.com/learn/api-design/what-are-microservices/)
- Parts of data are used by multiple applications (splitting into multiple databases for load distribution)

Do note that the distribution of data comes with some disadvantages, such as syncing data between databases (foreign keys could be hard to manage), and data mismatch between applications/application states.

Further, you can always start with a single database and later split them, as long as your data schema allows some flexibility between tables, for example, don't mash all data in a single table.

To give a definite answer to your question we would need to know more about the environment/architecture of the application.

I hope this helps you somewhat :)

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helped! I was looking for some "Why?" and "When" :)

Comment: You're welcome, if you found my answer helpful, click the arrow left of the post to mark the answer as 'helpful'